# Salt - Ubuntu Master... Redhat Minion - Fingerprint Mismatch

Tags: ubuntu, key, redhat, fingerprint, salt-stack

I'm having problems with a Master/Minion fingerprint mismatch.

- My Salt Master is on an Ubuntu 16.04 server.
- Minion #1 is on a second Ubuntu 16.04 server.
- And Minion #2 is on a Redhat 7.3 server.

All 3 of these servers are AWS EC2's.

Both of the minions have successfully connected to the master. And the Ubuntu Master sees the correct fingerprint for Ubuntu Minion #1...

***However, the Ubuntu Master and Redhat Minion #2 show different fingerprints when I run this on the Ubuntu Master:***

`$ sudo salt-key -f ip-xxx-xx-x-xx.ec2.internal << for Redhat Minion #2 ... the actual IP address is masked here >>`

My install steps for the **Ubuntu Master** were:

```
$ sudo apt update -y
$ sudo apt upgrade -y
$ sudo apt update -y
$ wget -O - https://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/16.04/amd64/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update -y
$ sudo apt install salt-master
$ sudo systemctl restart salt-master
```

My install steps for **Ubuntu Minion #1** were:

```
$ sudo apt update -y
$ sudo apt upgrade -y
$ sudo apt update -y
$ wget -O - https://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/16.04/amd64/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update -y
$ sudo apt install salt-minion
$ sudo systemctl restart salt-minion

$ sudo nano /etc/salt/minion
    << I made two changes to the file: (1) master = master's IP address, and (2) master_finger = master's fingerprint >>
$ sudo service salt-minion restart
```

And my install steps for the **Redhat Minion #2** were:

```
$ sudo yum update -y
$ sudo yum upgrade -y
$ sudo yum update -y
$ sudo yum install https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-1.el7.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install salt-minion
$ sudo yum install nano
$ sudo nano /etc/salt/minion
    << I made two changes to the file: (1) master = master's IP address, and (2) master_finger = master's fingerprint >>
$ sudo service salt-minion restart
```

These instructions were from the Salt docs.

https://repo.saltstack.com/#ubuntu

https://repo.saltstack.com/#rhel

So I'm not sure what the disconnect is. I also tried installing the Ubuntu master and minions via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saltstack/salt`. But that yielded the same results.

As a last ditch effort, I simply tried pinging Redhat Minion #2 (after accepting its key), but it didn't return a response... However, Ubuntu Minion #1 does return a response, so this isn't a general connection issue.

I can't seem to find much via google or a SO search. Are any of you running masters and minions with different OS's (specifically, Ubuntu and Redhat)? Have any of you run across this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my Ubuntu Master (and Minion) was a version behind the Redhat Minion. And I think my Ubuntu servers did not install the latest version of SaltStack because I was using "**apt update**", "**apt install**", etc. (as opposed to the traditional "**apt-get udpate**"). As soon as I used "apt-get", I was able to install the latest version of Salt on Ubuntu, and all of the fingerprints finally synced up.

I was under the impression that these latest versions of Ubuntu no longer required the use of "apt-get", and just using "apt" would suffice. And honestly, I've been using only "apt" for over a year with no real issues. But I definitely got burned today.

Feels kind of scuzzy to mark this as the answer, so I won't. But I'm not sure if that violates SO policy. Guess I'm living on the edge.